# Internal reference voltage of Voltage Regulator - what does it depend on?

Tags: voltage-regulator, battery-charging

I know this might be somehow specific and narrow question but that issue bothers me.

I've implemented the BQ24450 charger controller circuit presented in figure 10 of http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24450.pdf on the PCB. The circuit is supplied with a 5W 12V solar cell, the charged battery is a 4Ah 6V SLA. The max current that this solar cell can produce is 0.36A. It basically is the same to Fig 10 of this document.

The float charge voltage at +BATT as I measured when it's charged is 6.72V (even though by Ra-Rd resistors values shall be of 6.86V)

My schematics is just a redraw and looks like this:
[image]
R19 (Replacement) is not populated.

I measured the VFB voltage, it never reaches 2.30V (internal reference Vref=2.30V) and it settles on 2.27V which for my implementation results in Vfloat voltage of 6.72V instead of 6.86V.

The datasheet says Vref can be in range of 2.275V - 2.325V with the nominal value of 2.30V. 
**What does this depend on exactly? Why in my implementation it never reaches 2.30V and settles on 2.27V instead, why isn't it 2.325V, how can I influence it?**

In my implementation I used MJD32CG instead of BD242 for Qext and S1A instead of 1N4001 for Dext, I really doubt it could make that difference.

I now wonder if I should recalculate Ra-Rb for Vref=2.27V or is that value going to decrease (or increase) afterwards anyway.

Comment: Plus, how much confidence do you have that your meter is accurate enough, and isn't reading 2.27V for a voltage of 2.30V? That's less than 1.5% error.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I first verified my meter with the regulated supply. 2.27V is moreover consistent to calculations, i.e lower output voltage matches 2.27V of Vref

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant section of the datasheet is below:

[image]

The manufacturer guarantees only that the reference will be between 2.275V and 2.325V **at 25°C Tj (junction temperature) and in FLOAT mode and with Vin = 10V**

It will change some unknown amount with temperature, but typically -3.5mV for every degree C the junction heats- so if the device is running at 50°C Tj it could be 88mV lower. It could be twice or half that different, there is **no** guarantee. Also it changes with input voltage, so it might be a few more mV different because of that.

The actual variation is due to manufacturing variations (doping, exactness of resistor ratios and so on) and is quite tightly controlled for an IC (+/-1% of nominal), which is about as good as your external resistor ratios will be if you use 1% tolerance resistors. If you wish to influence the voltages for charging, you can just modify the resistor values (Ra, Rb, Rc) to compensate for unit-to-unit variations in Vref, but compensating for temperature coefficient or line regulation would be more difficult.

[image]

Comment: How is that efficiently handled in case of batch manufacturing of  circuits, provided the variance of reference voltage can be as large as 2,2% in case of bq24450, the error is further increased by inaccuracy of other components, like resistors?

Answer (score 1):

You can't influence it; the exact value is an artifact of manufacturing. You must construct the rest of the circuit around it keeping in mind that it may be any value within that range (and in a few cases may be slightly outside of it).

Comment: There is a possibility that the solar cell is not capable of providing enough power to get to the regulated output voltage. Is Q1 saturated when Vref=2.27V? In other words, what is the value of Vce of Q1 when Vref = 2.27? Your solar cell max power voltage is very far away from your battery charging voltage, meaning that you are wasting most of the power the panel produces. But that is a separate issue.

Comment: @mkeith I'm actually testing it with a regulated power supply set to 12V@0.3A

Comment: Is there any chance that the supply current limiting? You might want to try increasing the current limit to see if it makes a difference. Or just measure Vce.